# Why does MySQL DATE_FORMAT function return NULL when formatting a TIME value?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select  DATE_FORMAT('8:48:30 AM', '%H:%i:%s')
```

It returns Null why ?

but when using

```
select  DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(), '%H:%i:%s')
```

It return formatted value.

Comment: I believe that DATE_FORMAT expects its first parameter to be DATETIME type not only TIME. BTW I checked and on recent mysql it also gives null in the second form with warning: Incorrect datetime value: '11:35:22'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's returning NULL because MySQL isn't successfully parsing the string into a valid `DATETIME` value.

To fix the problem, use the `STR_TO_DATE` function to parse the string into a `TIME` value,

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('8:48:30 AM', '%h:%i:%s %p')
```

Then, to get the `TIME` value converted to a string in a particular format, use the `TIME_FORMAT` function, e.g. 24-hour clock representation:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE( '8:48:30 AM', '%h:%i:%s %p'),'%H:%i:%s')
```

returns:

```
--------
08:48:30
```

Comment: there is not function named `STR_TO_TIME ` in mysql

Answer (score 2):

The method `DATE_FORMAT` is used to display date and time, however in the first you are not assigning any date except time, so its is throwing `null`.

From the manuals -

> DATE_FORMAT Formats the date value according to the format string.

In MySql version 5.5 `SELECT DATE_FORMAT( CURTIME( ) , '%H:%i:%s' )` returns `null`

Answer (score 2):

`DATE_FORMAT` 's first parameter is of type `DATETIME`. On recent mysql server versions both your queries return NULL.

So the answer to your question is that this difference in behaviour is because of a bug in your mysql version - in some way it converts the `TIME` to `DATETIME`, while it cannot convert the string to `DATETIME`.

Here is also an example of a working query:

```
select  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s')
```

`NOW()` returns a `DATETIME` while `CURTIME()` returns `TIME`.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, I think it's because MySQL recognises the function as a time, and therefore knows how to handle it. Whereas, in the first example, it regards it as a string and doesn't know what to do with it.